# If he is given a chance, If a chance is given him and given a chance

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

I know we use **will** in 1st conditional sentences. For example:

Active >If we give him a chance, he will do the best in painting.

Passive >If he is given a chance (by us), he will do the best in painting.

But I want to use "can" to show his ability, so,
I have used **can** with an **If clause** in the following sentences:

> If he is given a chance, he can do the best in painting.
>
> If a chance is given him, he can do the best in painting.
>
> Given a chance, he can do the best in painting.

I don't know if these sentences are grammatically correct or not. Although these sentences are in (or with?) different sentence constructions, they imply the same meanings.

Comment: "...he can do the best in painting." simply doesn't sound right.  _If he is given a chance, he would excel at painting._  A common phrase in England is; _given half a chance..._

Comment: Info: See [meta about tags](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/is-this-tag-useful-episode-1-the-big-boss-grammar). You should avoid using the [tag:grammar] tag because it is far too broad, almost every question on ELL could be tagged *grammar*, use it only when you really haven't clue how to tag your posts! Although some will disagree with me even on this...

Comment: The sentences express the same thought and are grammatical in English, but as Mr Dark notes, a native speaker reading them would immediately identify the writer as a non-native speaker.

Comment: I used **can** because I think as:

**Active voice**: They give him a chance.

**Passive voice**: he is given a chance by them.

I just removed "them" and used the rest of the sentence= he is given a chance.

I didn't use "will" and wanted to use "can" in 'if clause'.


If there was "If there was "were" instead of "are", I would use "could" in the sentence.

For example, If he were given a chance, he could do the best in painting.

Comment: @P.E Dent Have you used "would" as conditional in your comment in " but as Mr Dark notes, a native speaker reading them **would** immediately identify the writer as a non-native speaker."

I don't know how it has been used as conditional, Is it implied conditional?

Comment: I use _would_ in my comment as the _predictive would._ We use it to talk about the result of an expected situation. Every dictionary includes this usage, e.g. [**Collins.**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/would)

Answer (score 1):

These sentences are conditional type 1.  You usually use will in the main clause, but it's also correct to use other modals such as can, may, might, should.

So all the sentences are correct grammatically.  The sentences starting with "Given a chance" and "If he is given a chance" are preferable to "If a chance is given him".

Answer (score 1):

According to oxford practical grammar book, conditional sentences that contain ability keep the modal verb as it is. 
If he is given a chance, he can do the best in painting.

[image]